# OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:380: starting container process caused: exec: no such file or directory: unknown

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I want to run a docker-compose file but I keep getting

> ERROR: for service2  Cannot start service service2: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:380: starting container process caused: exec: "./wait.sh": stat ./wait.sh: no such file or directory: unknown

and my docker-compose file is

```
version: "3"
services:
  service1:
    restart: always
    container_name: service1
    build: ./service1
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB
      - POSTGRES_USER
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD

  service2:
    container_name: service2
    build: ./service2
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB
      - POSTGRES_USER
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD
    depends_on:
      - service1
    restart: "no"
    volumes:
      - ./data.csv:/data.csv
    command: ["./wait.sh", "service1:5432", "--", "python", "./service2.py"]
```

but if I go and try to build *Dockerfile* for service2 everything is ok and I can run *wait.sh*.
Here's Dockerfile for service2:

```
FROM python:latest
WORKDIR /service2
RUN pip install psycopg2==2.8.6
COPY ./service2.py .
COPY ./wait.sh ./wait.sh
RUN chmod +x ./wait.sh
```

I completely don't get what's wrong especially because when I first ran `docker-compose up` the same error occured. But after that error did not occur for several times I ran `docker-compose up` and now again it doesn't work though I run the same docker-compose file.

*wait.sh* was taken from [here](https://github.com/vishnubob/wait-for-it)

*service2.py* connects to db and writes from *data.scv* but since it doesn't even run that should not be the problem.

Comment: could you try to specify a full path to the `wait.sh` file and `service2.py` in the command value of your docker-compose.yaml?

Comment: What is the very very first line of `wait.sh` (should be something like `#!/bin/sh`)?  Is it possible the file has DOS line endings?

Comment: surprisingly today this error doesn't come up though i did not change files. but now it says: ./wait.sh: 75: Syntax error: "(" unexpected (expecting ";;") though i can run wait.sh file directly; 
I tried the absolute path in docker-compose file yesterday but it couldn't help